# Book's class page margins in ClassicThesis 

Tags: margins, classicthesis

how can obtain the normal page margins (that provided from book class) on the ClassThesis?

i have try to comment this commands in ClassicThesis.sty

```
         {% Palatino or other
            \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{A4 paper, Palatino or other}
            \areaset[current]{336pt}{750pt} % ~ 336 * factor 2 + 33 head + 42 \the\footskip 
         \areaset{336pt}{761pt} % 686 (factor 2.2) + 33 head + 42 head \the\footskip 10pt     
            \setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
           \setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%
       }%
```

Comment: I would say: using `book` rather than `ClassicThesis`? Could you improve your question by specifying better what you mean for `normal page layout`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino sorry, i would that the margins disposition in ClassicThesis be equale to the margins disposition provided from the book class.

Answer (score 2):

The question makes little sense; however, you get essentially the same layout as the `book` class with

```
\usepackage[verbose]{geometry}
\geometry{innermargin=100pt,top=125pt,
  textwidth=345pt,textheight=598pt,
  marginparwidth=115pt,marginparsep=7pt,
  heightrounded}
```

Comment: thanks ! do you say that the question have little sense because if i need the book layout why do not i use that class? because i would to have all the personalizations that have the classic thesis but i prefer the margin given from book class

Comment: @FormlessCloud An overall style like ClassicThesis's does not mix well with every page layout. For example, the chapter headings are not, in my opinion, suitable for the large textwidth of the `book` class.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using geomtry (`classicthesis` is base on `KOMAscript` and include a similar functionality  through `areaset`) I suggest you take the number 345pt, multiply it with 2 (or 2.2), add 33pt + 42pt to the result, i.e.:

```
{% Palatino or other
   \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{A4 paper, Palatino or other}
   \areaset[current]{345pt}{768pt} % ~ 345 * factor 2 + 33 head + 42 \the\footskip 
   \areaset{345pt}{815pt} % 740 (factor 2.2) + 33 head + 42 head \the\footskip    
       \setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
       \setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%
   }%
```

Then you at least change the margins in a consistent way. Be aware that you typeblock neither will be a golden section or a double square, the recommended typeblocks for A4 paper sheet. I quote from page 4 in the manual:

> The size of the text body is intentionally shaped like it is. It
>   supports both legibility and allows a reasonable amount of information
>   to be on a page. And, no: the lines are not too short.

So I assume that you know what you are doing and why (see the requirement in the `classicthesis` manual:

> Therefore, please do not break the beauty of the style by changing
>   these things unless you really know what you are doing! Please.

If you find the margin to wide, it is the auhtor’s intention: *You can use these margins for summaries of the text body ...* (ref. the margin note at page 4 in the manual).