# Typesetting Classicthesis without margin notes

Tags: margins, classicthesis, marginnote

I am using classicthesis-v4.1 Lyx template for my thesis. I know that it is not advisable to make many changes in classicthesis.sty but I don't want to use the margin notes option in it. I would like

1. to remove the space on the outer margin dedicated to margin notes. I would like instead to move the text body towards the outer margin (over the current margin notes):
   [image: text body shifted to the right]
2. to either wrap or truncate too long chapter titles in the header, an example:
   [image: too long chapter title]

---

I tried the following solutions:

1. Simply not using margin notes; the space is still reserved for them:
   [image: empty margin note column]
2. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95713/remove-marginpar-from-classicthesis-4-1), which revolves around making the following change:

```
\areaset[current]{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}{\textheight}
```

This, however, enlarges the text width, which is not what I want
(ignore the example margin notes):
[image: too large text width]

3. [This other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66837/books-class-page-margins-in-classicthesis?rq=1) which instead sets the lengths manually:

```
\areaset[current]{345pt}{768pt} % ~ 345 * factor 2 + 33 head + 42 \the\footskip 
\areaset{345pt}{815pt} % 740 (factor 2.2) + 33 head + 42 head \the\footskip    
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%
```

which does not seem to do what I want:
[image: still margins]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: We'll need some example code here to have a chance of helping.

Comment: For anyone else puzzled by this: you need to increase the `BCOR` (the binding correction) in the document class. This will shift the text towards the outer side and shrink the note width. The margin notes take whatever space is left after the page width and the binding correction are added. I also think the question is clear, but I had no luck at reopening it by editing.